# Retrieving data from two tables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle

I have two tables `vendors` and `customers`. My problem is that I want to make the search of the name and in result I get the common data from both the tables(if any exist).
Example: If I search the name John and it exits in both the tables so in result I must get the gridviews of both the tables.

Comment: you should add some code - in this way the question is too generic - it's difficult to help you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear for me. Are you looking for a SQL statement?

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM Vendors LEFT JOIN Customers ON Vendors.Name = Customers.Name
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE Vendors.Name IN (SELECT Customers.Name FROM Customers)
```